# SP2010 Incoming Email Message Not Working

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

I was able to configure incoming email settings to work. I send a test email and it creates the item fine but it only imports the TITLE of the email but nowhere of the body message is in the list item.

I tried enabling to save the original email as an .eml file and when I open the .eml file in outlook I also cannot see the body message.

Please advise, thank you!

Comment: Did you enter anything in the body of the mail?

Comment: Yes i entered text into the body

Comment: so i got it working if i force my outlook to send the email as plain text. Does SharePoint not support HTML incoming emails?

Comment: What was the base list type ? I.e. it will capture documents for emails and for meeting invite, calender list needs to be created.